# Nativescript Pull to Refresh not working

Tags: nativescript

I was trying to use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-pulltorefresh but it returns the error below...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.AXMetrix/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreateView failed

Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/views/tabs/tabs.xml:46:25
 ���Building UI from XML. @file:///app/views/tabs/metrix/metrix.xml:42:1
   ���Module 'ui/pull-to-refresh' not found for element 'PullToRefresh'.
   ���com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "ui/pull-to-refresh", relative to: /app/tns_modules/
      com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:220)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
    com.tns.FragmentClass.onCreateView(FragmentClass.java:35)
    android.app.Fragm
```

This is the link of the 2 xml files that I have inserted codes to make the plugin work...

http://plnkr.co/edit/TTEM1tA5HbnxM94QJl3H

And this is my dir structure for my project...

[image]

Comment: Your UI markup is probably wrong. Add your xml here rather than plunkr please. Plnkr is awful on mobile for me.

Comment: The markup is so long for the space here...

Comment: Oh lol that sucks too :)

Answer (score 0):

I pulled it up on plnkr (can't pan the xml on my phone) so not 100% but you need to declare the plugin namespace. Check the README for correct declaration and then it will work.